# Can I use Shift-Space in a tmux keybinding?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

I've been using (prefixed) `o` to zoom the current tmux pane, and `Space` to zoom the neighboring pane:

```
bind o      resize-pane -Z
bind Space  if-shell -F '#{window_zoomed_flag}' 'last-pane' 'select-pane -t :.+; resize-pane -Z'
```

I want to change these to use `Space` and `Shift-Space` instead.

```
bind Space    resize-pane -Z
bind S-Space  if-shell -F '#{window_zoomed_flag}' 'last-pane' 'select-pane -t :.+; resize-pane -Z'
```

I restarted my tmux server and ran `tmux list-keys`. The new bindings are listed, and the first binding works as expected, but I'm having trouble passing `S-Space` through to tmux for the second binding.

Using iTerm (I'm on OSX) with its default settings, <kbd>⇧Shift</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> ignores the <kbd>⇧Shift</kbd> modifier, so when I type `<prefix> S-Space`, tmux just receives `<prefix> Space`.

I actually configure iTerm to send escape sequence `^[[32;2u` for <kbd>⇧Shift</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> so I can use it for Vim key-mappings. With this setting active, typing `<prefix> S-Space` in tmux inserts `32;2u` on the command line.

I tried to debug using `cat -v` inside tmux:

```
^[[32;2u    # S-Space
32;2u       # <prefix> S-Space
```

Is there a different escape sequence that tmux would recognize as `S-Space`, or some other way to make it work?

I read a bit about tmux's `terminal-overrides` setting, but that sounds like it's only for control sequences. I use `C-a` as my prefix key, if that's relevant.

Answer (score 3):

short: no

long: unless you have changed your keyboard mapping, <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> will send just <kbd>space</kbd>.

Aside from a few other special keys (<kbd>Enter</kbd>), you might expect <kbd>shift</kbd> to modify the character(s) sent by the keyboard.  This is not *always* the case.  Most of the ones you are familiar with are based on **`xterm`**, e.g., using <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>control</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd> (or <kbd>meta</kbd>) to generate different escape sequences.

`tmux` "knows" about the `xterm` keys (and has a mode which can be set to permit it to use those keys).  Otherwise (if `xterm-keys` is not set), if the key matches the terminal description for one of the known special keys (function- and cursor- and editing-keys such as <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd>), `tmux` accepts that key (and maps it into the `screen` or whatever "internal" terminal description is used).

If the key does not fall into one of those categories, `tmux` ignores it (discards it).

So... if you want to use <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>space</kbd>, you will have to make it send one of the escape sequences which `tmux` expects, and make your binding against the corresponding predefined capability.

Further reading:

- [Tmux eats control tab sequence](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167429/tmux-eats-control-tab-sequence)
- [How to get the F1-F4 keys to behave normally in tmux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296546/how-to-get-the-f1-f4-keys-to-behave-normally-in-tmux)